# WCF consumer doesn't get response within the timeout limit, although the service itself is done

Tags: wcf, connection, timeout

We have two applications. 1 client application and 1 web service. The client calls the webservice, which starts processing. This takes a while. If it exceeds 240 seconds, then the client never receives a response from the service. Even though the service is done after 260 seconds. The client keept waiting until it's timeout (10 minutes) is reached. Then a timeout exception occurs on the client.

We don't experience this behavior on Windows 2012R2 with IIS 7,5. We do experience this behavior on Windows 2016 with IIS 10.

It must be some setting in the binding or connection somewhere. But I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

About the practical timeout meaning of the binding in WCF, please refer to the below official document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding
As far as I know, if the `sendtimeout` value on the client is less than the consumption time that the server-side process the method to be called. There will occur that timeout exception.
Additional, the timeout error does not mean that the issue is mainly related to the timeout property, or something wrong with the configuration. such as we have not enabled the `Windows feature` support for WCF on your server-side. I would like to know more information about your server-side.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: WCF Windows feature is enabled, because it works fine when the processing takes less than about 4 minutes.
About the timeout: the processing takes LESS than the timeout value, but the client doesn't get the response, that's the actual problem...

Comment: try to configure the `sendtime` property of the binding on the client-side. Besides, what is the inner exception, does it relate to the database connection?