# wcf consumer doesnt get response within the timeout limit although the service works correctly

Tags: wcf, server, client

i'm suffering the same issue as
[WCF consumer doesn't get response within the timeout limit, although the service itself is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974010/wcf-consumer-doesnt-get-response-within-the-timeout-limit-although-the-service)
here, timeouts are set correctly. other application like soapui are getting response back from server on the same client.

also not getting any error, just wait until timeout is reached, this is on a Windows 2019 with IIS 10. Client is a win32 application on Windows 10. When connecting to windows 2008 it is getting the right response

I managed to rebuild the dll's on .net 4.8 but no difference on the response.
Any help ?

Comment: What is the response time of your WCF Consumer app and whether it will be less than the return time of the server processing method.Also you could check that Windows support for WCF is enabled on the server side.

Comment: Jiayao since other apps like soapui work fine, this can not be the issue. Also timings are correct. Windows support for WCF is enabled

Comment: Is the problem solved? Is there any other error message according to the method.